# Should I use cookies?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I created a website in ASP. People can login and register.

I read sometimes about cookies, why people are using them?

What is the advantage of using them? And do you guys prefer me to use that too?

And if I use cookies, for what kind of purporses should I use them?

Thanks!

Comment: Learn about cookies here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289495(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You're coming at this the wrong way.  You don't use cookies to use cookies.  You use cookies because something you want to do requires cookie use.

In other words, don't worry about it unless you want to do something that needs cookies, then you know why you would want to use them.  It becomes obvious.

It's like saying "I hear about these airplane thingies.. should I use them?  What good are they?"  Well, when you decide you want to travel somewhere, suddenly you understand what good they are.  They're useless to you until then.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are useful for retaining information when the user leave your website.
For example, if you want an option "Remember me" on your login form, you have to use cookies to store user's authentication token and connect him automatically the next time he visits your website.

But if you use it, you should learn more about it.